# Debuggin short codes (If you dont mind helping me)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am a beginner in Javascript, I am trying to make a website that can show image. the HTML is like this (main part):

```js
//And my Javascript : 

document.getElementById('category').innerHTML = row.category[count]
document.getElementById('bbox').style.left=row.x1[count]
document.getElementById('bbox').style.left=row.x1[count]
document.getElementById('bbox').style.top=row.y1[count]
document.getElementById('bbox').style.width=row.x2[count]-row.x1[count]
document.getElementById('bbox').style.height=row.y2[count]-row.y1[count]
```

```css
/*I set the style in my css file, which is different file with my HTML :*/
#previewimage{
 width: 500px;
/* height: 100%*/
 z-index: 1;
 position: absolute;
}

#bbox{
 width: 100px;
 z-index: 3;
 position: relative;
 height: 100px;
 border: 5px dashed black;
 left: 150px;
 top:200px;
}
```

```html
<div id="images">
    <img src="img/80673284_74c3361ed19c018192c338d338d27d67.jpg" id="previewimage">
    <img id="bbox">
</div>
```

Now the problem is why, if I put my javascript line on a button, it change randomly, It is like set the left, top to 0 and width and height remains constant.
Any idea ?

Comment: what is `row` in your code? and your problem is not clear.

Comment: var row = {
  link: [],
  category: [],
  x1: [],
  x2: [],
  y1: [],
  y2: []
};

Comment: add a sample of row in your code in question. And what javascript line on button are putting? your question is not clear

Comment: Basically, I am expecting, when I press the button, all the document.getElementByID will execute and change my img(with id bbox). But it is not happening

Comment: there is no button in your code.

Comment: Hi Dij, Thanks for answering, I got it already  :)

Answer (score 0):

got it!
I just forgot to put px
LOL this is funny